# System.IO.File.ReadAllText is not working for web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, web-applications, io

I given the following code on web service. It is not working for me.

```
string xmlReport = " ";
xmlReport = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(uriReportSource.Uri);
```

And I am using this uri: `C:/Shared/PrimaryContact.trdx`

I receive this error:

> The given path's format is not supported.
>
> at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity,
>   IDictionary2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity
>   workflow, IDictionary2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout,
>   WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions) at
>   System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow,
>   IDictionary`2 inputs) at Aceo.Hub.ActivityService.Process(HubRequest
>   request)

Comment: What error/exception are you receiving ?

Comment: The given path's format is not supported. at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout) at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions) at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs) at Aceo.Hub.ActivityService.Process(HubRequest request)

Comment: Probably your parameter : `uriReportSource.Uri` doesn't seem to match the expected way. Check it and correct it if needed.

Comment: The class is `System.IO.File`, not `System.IO.Uri` or something. Use a WebClient.

Comment: ‪C:/Shared/PrimaryContact.trdx i am getting url in this form that is correct

Comment: Please edit your post with information you've added in comments. Also debug your code and provide exact value inline in the post instead of some unknown variable.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using stream reader

```
     string xmlReport = " ";
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(uriReportSource.Uri))
                {
                    xmlReport = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

This will work